# Alive or Idle connections on JDBC

Tags: jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp, hikaricp, jdbc-pool

It seems that [JDBC Spec](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) does not elaborate the accurate meanings of `alive or idle connections` in the datasource connection pool. Is it just implementation specific? How does [DBCP2](https://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) actually inspect the connection status?

Will a connection without active transactions be marked idle below?

```java
// assuming auto commit disabled already

Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection(); // idle?
/* issue some JDBC SQL statements */ // active?
connection.commit(); /* or rollback */ //idle again?
```

Comment: JDBC doesn't talk about idle, because idle is not relevant for JDBC. However usually (but not always), idle is used to refer to connections in the pool (which means that they are not checked out).

Answer (score 3):

You should distinct between **idle** / **borrowed** pooled connections (as discussed by Nathan) *and* **valid** / **invalid** connections.

Those attributes are orthogonal, but typically there is a property e.g. *testOnBorrow* for [Tomcat Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) which when set can enforce that the borrowed connection is valid (i.e. is able to execute the validation query).

Also a time limit can be set to remove connection that are idle for a long time from the  connection pool (e.g. *minEvictableIdleTimeMillis*). Similar is valid for removal of **abandoned** connections, i.e those that were "forgotten" to be returned to the pool by the application. (*removeAbandonedTimeout*).

You are right it's all *implementation specific*.

Answer (score 2):

"Idle" means the connection isn't currently being loaned out. (As Mark Rotteveel says in the comments, this isn't relevant to the JDBC spec, since JDBC doesn't specifically deal with connection pools.) "Active" means the connection is valid and can be used. It's easy to tell if something is idle, since the pool is explicitly keeping track of that, and harder to know if it's valid, because it's a network connection and could fail anytime.

A connection pool checks the status of connections by running some test sql on the connection, where the sql is usually supplied through a configuration property, something trivial like "select 1 from dual".

Comment: Could you make a short example of idle connection?

Comment: @sof: "idle" means the connection is created and is sitting in the pool but nothing is using it currently. I don't know what kind of example you would want.

Comment: @sof start the application but don't allow the clients to connect - all connections in the pool will be idle.